# How do I change the perspective of a 3d cylinder in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, 3d, perspective

I have produced a 3d cylinder in Photoshop.  I would like to save it as a jpeg, and place it over a mug mock up.  However the perspective of the cylinder and mug mock up are both different.

Thanks

Comment: Add a screenshot (the problem well visible) and tell have you 3D models or only flat images? Otherwise you get round and nasty sounding answers that probably are useless. I added one to see.

Answer (score 1):

Return to the 3D mode (hopefully you have saved the non-flat PSD) and move the camera in the options panel. Have the distance and viewing angle that you want.

[image]